# Is it possible set group each UNION on MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query and I want to set a group for each union.

```
SELECT
    model, 
    model_id
FROM
    erk
WHERE
    5000 between `min` and `max`
UNION ALL
SELECT
    model,
    model_id
FROM
    erk2
WHERE
    15000 between `min` and `max`
```

Here are the results:

```
model_id   model
1           20
2           40
3           60
6           150
7           200
8           250
9           300
```

So, I want to display the results of each value (5000 and 15000)
For example, first select with value 5000 brings the models 20,40,60. The second select brings 150,200,250,300

Should I set extra column with sql like below and recognize which results has been fetched from which select?

```
model_id   model   group
1           20      1
2           40      1
3           60      1
6           150     2
7           200     2
8           250     2
9           300     2
```

Setting group Id I am able to know which row comes from which select.. Or maybe there is another method to recognize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the group as fields with a constant value:

```
SELECT
    model, 
    model_id,
    1 as result_group
FROM
    erk
WHERE
    5000 between `min` and `max`
UNION ALL
SELECT
    model,
    model_id,
    2 as result_group
FROM
    erk2
WHERE
    15000 between `min` and `max`
```

Comment: @vitalik_74 because the word group is a key word for mysql. must be `group`. But I accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
  SELECT
        model, 
        model_id,
        1 AS `group`
    FROM
        erk
    WHERE
        5000 between `min` and `max`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        model,
        model_id,
        2 AS `group`
    FROM
        erk2
    WHERE
        15000 between `min` and `max`
```